# Table Placement and Caption Problem

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am having trouble using the `table` and `tabular` functions within LaTeX. I want to have two tables neatly placed over each other with the caption centered under the tables. One of my graphs is placed to the right so it does not fit on the page and the captions are not centered under the tables. Here is my code and a JPG pic of my problem. Any help is muchly appreciated.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\parbox{.1\linewidth}{
%\centering
%\caption{Groupsof4}
%\label{fme}
\tabcolsep=0.05cm
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccccc}
Gr 1    & Gr 2   & Gr 3  & Gr 4   & Gr 5  & Gr 6  & Gr 7  & Gr 8  & Gr 9  & Gr 10  & Gr 11   & Gr 12  & Gr 13  & Gr 14\\
\hline
 9&29&12&25&33&14&6&15&3&18&43&2&7&1\\
16&35&17&26&45&42&27&19&13&23&44&4&8&5\\
30&36&28&40&47&46&38&24&20&32&48&11&37&10 \\
55&51&31&52&50&49&53&34&22&39&54&56&41&21\\
%\caption{Groupsof4}
\hline
%\caption{Groupsof4}
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Groups of 4}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]

\parbox{.1\linewidth}{
\centering
%\caption{Groupsof14}
\label{dt1}
\tabcolsep=0.11cm
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccccc}
Gr 1    & Gr 2   & Gr 3  & Gr 4  \\
\hline
9&6&3&1\\
16&14&11&2\\
25&15&13&4 \\
26&19&18&5\\
26&19&18&5\\
29&24&20&7\\
30&27&22&8\\
33&34&23&10\\
35&38&32&12\\
36&42&39&17\\
40&46&43&21\\
45&47&44&28\\
51&49&48&31\\
52&50&54&37\\
55&53&56&41\\

\hline
\end{tabular}

}
\caption{Groups of 14}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: For me, removing the `\parbox` in both tables results in horizontally centered tables with centered captions.

Comment: Thanks leandriis.  That made table 5.1 centered in the page but the caption of table 5.2 is still not centered under the table. I have attached the picture of the problem with the code.

Comment: As you have not provided a real MWE, I was only able to guess. To be able to help you a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/134144) including the document class and packages is needed.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

[image]

you have more problems in your code snippet:

- since you provide only table code and not inform us about used `\documentclass{...}` and settings for page layout i'm not sure if your first table is to wide to be placed on text area of page. in standard `article` as well with reduced margin by `geometry settings first table is to wide, so i suggest to use`tabular*`  (see *mwe* below).
- i remove all `parbox` which purpose is not clear.

  by the way: width of each `\parbox` is to small that can contain your tables. for test try:

  \parbox{\linewidth}{ % not 0.1\linewidth !
  \centering
  %\caption{Groupsof4}
  %\label{fme}
  \begin{tabular}{ ... }
  ...
  \end{tabular}
  }

e has wrong width; if you set their width as `\parbox{\linewidth}` your problem will disappear.
- in second table you define 14 columns, but use only four.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\ \extracolsep{\fill}}*{14}{c}@{\ }}
Gr 1    & Gr 2   & Gr 3  & Gr 4   & Gr 5  & Gr 6  & Gr 7  & Gr 8  & Gr 9  & Gr 10  & Gr 11   & Gr 12  & Gr 13  & Gr 14\\
\hline
 9&29&12&25&33&14& 6&15& 3&18&43& 2& 7& 1\\
16&35&17&26&45&42&27&19&13&23&44& 4& 8& 5\\
30&36&28&40&47&46&38&24&20&32&48&11&37&10\\
55&51&31&52&50&49&53&34&22&39&54&56&41&21\\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Groups of 4}
\label{tab:first}% or whatever  label name
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}% not {cc cc cc cc cc cc cc} !
Gr 1    & Gr 2   & Gr 3  & Gr 4  \\
\hline
9&6&3&1\\
16&14&11& 2\\
25&15&13& 4\\
26&19&18& 5\\
26&19&18& 5\\
29&24&20& 7\\
30&27&22& 8\\
33&34&23&10\\
35&38&32&12\\
36&42&39&17\\
40&46&43&21\\
45&47&44&28\\
51&49&48&31\\
52&50&54&37\\
55&53&56&41\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Groups of 14}
\label{tab:second}% or whatever label name
\end{table}
\end{document}
```